# Using jQuery in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I've got a scope problem.

I have a class with a mouseX and mouseY property.

I wanted to set them using jQuery, like this:

```
// Store the mouse position at all times
$('#'+canvasId).mousemove( function(e) {
    this.mouseX = e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
    this.mouseY = e.pageY-this.offsetTop;
});
```

Works fine, only this.mouseX stays in the function scope.
I've implicitly declared mouseX and mouseY in the class using `this`.
If I don't they become private variables, right?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something more like the following:

```
// I usually put this at the top of my class declaration
var that = this;

// Store the mouse position at all times
$('#'+canvasId).mousemove( function(e) {
    that.mouseX = e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
    that.mouseY = e.pageY-this.offsetTop;
});
```

Since `this` changes meaning inside an event handler, you need to save a reference to it for later use; the conventional name for such a saved reference is `that`.

Comment: Oh, it's THAT easy. Should have thought outside of the box a bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your could do something along the lines of this:

```
// Store the mouse position at all times
var base = this;
// ...
$('#'+canvasId).mousemove( function(e) {
    base.mouseX = e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
    base.mouseY = e.pageY-this.offsetTop;
});
```

Oh, and yes. If you don't use `this` for variables within a class definition, you won't be able to access them through an instance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use little know [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function. Something like this:

```
var obj = {
  mouseX: 0,
  mouseY:0,
  el:$('#'+canvasId),
  mousemove: function(e) {
    this.mouseX = e.pageX-this.el.offsetLeft;
    this.mouseY = e.pageY-this.el.offsetTop;
  }
};

$('#'+canvasId).mousemove( jQuery.proxy( obj.mousemove, obj ) );
```

Of course you no longer get access to the original jQuery element via **this**, so you have to save it as a property of the object, something like **this.el**, beforehand

You can even create the event within the object like so:

```
this.el.mousemove( jQuery.proxy( this.mousemove, this ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've implicitly declared mouseX and
>   mouseY in the class using this. If I
>   don't they become private variables,
>   right?

Using `this` ties those properties to the current function scope (which in your case is the jquery mousemove function). If you remove the `this` then those variables will become globals. Private properties can be declared using `var`.

Private Variables:

```
// Store the mouse position at all times
$('#'+canvasId).mousemove( function(e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = e.pageY-this.offsetTop;
});
```

Global Variables:

```
// Store the mouse position at all times
$('#'+canvasId).mousemove( function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY-this.offsetTop;
});
```

Comment: To use those values in your class without creating new global variables, look at polarblau's and Domenic's answers.